# What are the options for Android apps that uses webview after API release 26

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, hybrid

I am an hobbyist coder mostly limited to PHP and mysql. I developed a website for one client who also asked me to present it as an android app.
So I made an hybrid app following some youtube tutorials. It worked fine mostly
but In android version 7 and version 8, webview is deprecated. they are using chrome instead.
Now can anybody please suggest me some alternative way to show my website as an app in android. 
also, can I migrate myapp from webview to chorome.

Answer (score 0):

webView is not Deprecated.

The Following method in webView is deprecated

Android has deprecated shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {} in WebViewClient and replaced it with it with shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest), presumably for greater long-term flexibility.

instead of using

```
boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)
```

use

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

Comment: thanks bro. I have two questions. One will it work on older APIs. Two: where should I make corrections.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean exit=false;
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.something.com");
        WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); }  
}

Comment: i am unable to write it hear i will give another answer

Answer (score 0):

create a method called initWebView in onCreate

```
private void initWebView() {
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request) {

webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
return true;
```

}
            }

this should do the job